# Let $E=[1,2,...n]$ where $n$ is an odd integer.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $E=[1,2,...n]$ where $n$ is an odd integer.
Let $V:$ vector space of all functions from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(f+g)(k)=f(k)+g(k)$  and $(\lambda f)(k)=\lambda f(k)$ where $k \in E$ and $f,g \in V$.
We need to find the dimension of $V$.
I am confused on how to check the linear independence of the functions in $V$.
Help

Comment: You check linear independence the same way you always do: is there a non-trivial linear combination which is equal to $0$? Try with $n=1$ and $n=3$ first, write down actual functions, add them together, see what you get. Then see if you can answer the questions for those cases. Then maybe you can go to the general case.

Comment: Yes, I actually got the independence case but I am not really sure about the dimension of $V$ whether it is $3$ or $3n$?

Comment: Well, if those arethe only two options you have to choose from: Take $n = 3$ and all shall become clear. Can you think of 4 linearly independent functions (using, say, 3 linearly independent functions you already know about from $n = 1$).